# UIScrollView not zooming: What am I missing?

Tags: swift, xcode, uiscrollview

I can scroll, but not zoom. I've seen a lot of identical looking code while searching, but still there's no zoom.

The pinchGestureRecognizer is not `nil`.

`viewForZoomingInScrollView(scrollView: UIScrollView)` is not being called.

`scrollViewDidEndZooming(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, with view: UIView?, atScale scale: CGFloat)` reports scale = `1.0`.

What am I missing here?

(We need to do this programmatically rather than in IB).

```
import UIKit

class ScrollViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {

    var scrollView: UIScrollView!
    var imageView: UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        imageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "image.png"))

        scrollView = UIScrollView(frame: view.bounds)
        scrollView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
        scrollView.contentSize = imageView.bounds.size
        scrollView.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: 1000, y: 450)

        scrollView.addSubview(imageView)
        view.addSubview(scrollView)

        scrollView.delegate = self
        scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 0.1
        scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 4.0
        scrollView.zoomScale = 1.0
    }

    //delegate
    func viewForZoomingInScrollView(scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {
        return imageView
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you convert your codes from an older version of Swift? Because the delegate function for returning the view for zooming is now

```
func viewForZooming(in scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView?
```